# Get Page Main Content using the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I need to be able to get the page main content from a certain url.
a very good example on what i need to do is the following: [http://embed.ly/docs/explore/preview?url=http%3A%2F%2Fedition.cnn.com%2F2012%2F08%2F20%2Fworld%2Fmeast%2Fflight-phobia-boy-long-way-home%2Findex.html%3Fiid%3Darticle_sidebar](http://embed.ly/docs/explore/preview?url=http://edition.cnn.com/2012/08/20/world/meast/flight-phobia-boy-long-way-home/index.html?iid=article_sidebar)

I am using asp.net with C# language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parsing html pages and guessing the main content is not an easy process. I would recomment to use [NReadability](http://code.google.com/p/nreadability/) and [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Here is an example how it could be done. Main text is always in `div` with id `readInner` after NReadability transcoded the page.

```
string url = "http://.......";

var t = new NReadability.NReadabilityWebTranscoder();
bool b;
string page = t.Transcode(url, out b);

if (b)
{
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(page);

    var title = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//title").InnerText;
    var text = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='readInner']")
                  .InnerText;
}
```

Comment: this is a very helpful answer, do you think the link i added use a technique like this to get content from whatever website we provide a link for? also i couldn't find NReadability dll, can u provide a link please

Comment: @AliIssa the link is in the answer. Click  on NReadability on the 2nd line.

Comment: couldn't find which one in this folder https://github.com/marek-stoj/NReadability

Comment: @AliIssa left-bottom of the linked page

Comment: this method seems to be obsolete now and does not render the complete html. Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Man,

I guess it's made using the implementation of [WebClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or [WebRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx). With it you can download all content of page then using any data mining algorithm, you can get the information you want.

[]'s

Comment: I think what OP really asks is that `data mining algorithm`

Comment: @L.B Ok, I agree that the HtmlAgilityPack is an implementation of a data mining algorithm, however, as the question is vague because it does not know what he wants for the content, HtmlAgilityPack may not be a good solution.

Comment: HAP in fact is an Html Parser, The real logic is in NReadability. BTW, I tested the above code before posting.